# When debugging in netbeans debugging line jump to FutureTask.java and how can I control it

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a code without coding errors and when debugging that code suddenly jump debugging line into a java class which name is FutureTask.java. So after that i can't do my debugging and identify errors because can't enter again into my code from FutureTask.java. So how can i control this..

Comment: Can you please provide an example as [described in the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problem with libraries you have used. FutureTask.java may be not implemented in the library file. So you can replace your library files to newer version.